# C/C++ Inline assembly [with C loops]

Tags: c++, c, assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OPT //define for assembly

int main()
{
 char chr;
 for(chr = 'A' ; chr <= 'Z' ; chr++)
 {
  #ifdef OPT
  __asm
  {
   lea eax,chr
   push eax
   mov eax, putchar
   call eax
   pop ebx
  }
  #endif

  #ifndef OPT
  putchar(chr);
  #endif 
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Upon usage of the assembly code, all that happens is a random trash-character is printed. Note this is in intel syntax.

Also:
I'm learning inline assembly, how would you grab the return value of a called function (through mov eax,func then call eax or equiv?)

Comment: What's wrong with just `call putchar` ?

Comment: TonyK, you cannot call putchar, because putchar is a variable. I think this is mainly for debugging purposes and can be turned on or off in C compiler settings.

Comment: @Aleš Keprt: That's a new one on me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because **lea** instruction is intended to get the address of a variable. (+1 to zebarbox for this note.) We need the value of chr, not its address, so we use this instead:

```
movsx eax,chr
```

This pseudoinstruction will compile to something like this:

```
movsx eax,[ebp-4]
```

You can also write putchar(chr), put there a breakpoint, run the application and look into disassembly window to see how it is compiled.

Note that I use **movsx** because chr is char and I need here a dword. If chr was int, I would simply use **mov** instruction.

Also, you are not allowed to use **pop ebx**, because ebx must not be changed here. Use **pop eax** or **add esp,4** instead.

Comment: lea is used to load the address of the variable into eax and so you'd use it if the function expected a pointer - it has nothing to do with static or global variables

Comment: I can do lea on a local variable if I want, not sure what you mean by constant address? i.e. char text[] = "Hello World";

 _asm
 {
  lea eax, text
  push eax
  call DWORD ptr printf
  pop eax
 }

Comment: zebrabox: Good point! Your text example works, because your lea retrieves adress of text array, not its value. The original example doesn't work with lea because we need the value of chr, not its address. Thank you for this note, I am going to add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your correct code:

```
int c = chr;
__asm
{
   mov  eax, c
   push eax
   mov  eax, putchar
   call eax
   pop  ebx
}
```

You cannot move `chr` on `eax`, due to size-conflict. So I used 'c' of `int` type!